# ServiceStack allow get on all endpoints while developing

Tags: c#, web-services, servicestack

I'm developing an API using service stack.

While developing it would be heaps easier if I could test all of my URLs using GET - in a browser.

say for instance I have a service which has the following:

```
public object Post(UserAccountRequest request){...}
public object Get(UserAccountRequest request){...}
public object Put(UserAccountRequest request){...}
```

and the `UserAccountRequest` looks like:

```
[Route("/Model/UserAccount", "POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,GET")]
[Route("/Model/UserAccount/{Id}")]
public class UserAccountRequest : IReturn<UserAccountResponse>
{...}
```

I would like to be able to call the Post method (using GET) by navigating to the URL `/Model/Post/UserAccount/?username=werw&email=werwer@werwr.com` and this would then be routed to the Post method and treated as a normal request (POST).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you try using my `MapVerbService` to map your requests?

Comment: I'm going to try it this am on the train :)

Comment: Sorry mate - I'm stuck on some Xamarin work atm - will be picking this up in about an hour :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to accept multiple HTTP request types on a method you should either use the `Any()` handler:

```cs
public MyUserService : Service
{
    public UserAccountResponse Any(UserAccountRequest request)
    {
        // All verbs handled here
    }
}
```

Or alternatively make your action handler private and call it from the http handler methods:

```cs
public MyUserService : Service
{
    public UserAccountResponse Get(UserAccountRequest request)
    {
        return HandleUserAccountRequest(request);
    }

    public UserAccountResponse Post(UserAccountRequest request)
    {
        return HandleUserAccountRequest(request);
    }

    private UserAccountResponse HandleUserAccountRequest(UserAccountRequest request)
    {
        // Do something useful
        return ...
    }
}
```

There is not built in functionality to remap the routes to actions the way you propose just for debugging, but you can roll-your-own. *See below*

---

### Map GET to other Verbs:

I created a really simple mapper Service. It uses a slightly different route format than you were going for, but should ultimately work.

> /t/post/Model/UserAccount/?username=werw&email=werwer@werwr.com

```cs
[Route("/t/{verb}/{path*}","GET")]
public class MapVerbRequest 
{
    public string Verb { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

public class MapVerbController : Service
{
    public object Get(MapVerbRequest request)
    {
        if(!Request.IsLocal)
            throw HttpError.Unauthorized("You can't do that!");

        // Determine the real path
        var raw = Request.AbsoluteUri.Replace(string.Format("/t/{0}",request.Verb), "");

        // Create a client
        var client = new JsonServiceClient();

        // Run the request with the desired verb
        return client.Send<object>(request.Verb, raw, "");
    }
}
```

---

## X-Http-Method-Override parameter

Another way you can do this is to just add the parameter `x-http-method-override=POST` to your GET query string during development. So you can also do:

> /Model/UserAccount/?username=werw&email=werwer@werwr.com&x-http-method-override=POST

*Where POST can be substituted for another VERB such as PUT, DELETE, PATCH etc*

Comment: Don't suppose you've ever done something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533859/servicestack-authentication-in-tests

Comment: @iwayneo I was just looking to see if I can cobble something that would do that :) Give me 10 mins.