# ServiceStack authentication in tests

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-auth

I want to be able to test my Servicestack endpoints using basic or credentials auth but don't want to have to login for each test, save the ss-id and then use that to actually exercise the end point.

Ideally I would be able to create a user using something like (this already works using credentials auth) http://devapi.someapi.com/register?username=blah&password=test&x-http-method-override=POST

then actually hit a secured url with something like:

http://devapi.someapi.com/users/123?username=blah&password=test

Is there anything like this available?

Answer (score 0):

For testing I recommend using `Config.AdminAuthSecret` to specify a special string to give you admin access without having to login by adding `?authsecret=xxx` to the query string.

Comment: If I try to access: http://devapi.someapi.com/users/123?authsecret=xxx I just get redirected to /login

Comment: I have the config set for adminauthsecret

Comment: @iwayneo what's in your Service? Can you provide a rerpo? I use it a lot myself.

Comment: I can add you to the repo? It's not huge and runs out of the box so no setup or dependencies needing install

Comment: @iwayneo yep sounds good, tho i'll have to check it tomorrow morning, 3am for me now.

Comment: Added you to the repo, I just pulled to a new machine to make sure it does load up and run out of the box and it did so you should be good to go :)

Comment: @iwayneo was hoping I could just look at a small repro, what service should I be looking at?

Comment: I've emailed servicestack support with some info - will you get that?